# SELECT ALL column_names in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm using `PostgreSQL` and I want to create a `query` that will display all `column_names` in a specific `table`.

```
Schema: codes

Table Name: watch_list
```

Here are the `column_names` in my `table`:

```
watch_list_id, watch_name, watch_description
```

I tried what I found in the web:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'codes'
  AND table_name   = 'watch_list'
```

It output is not what I wanted. It should be:

```
watch_list_id, watch_name, watch_description
```

How to do this?

Comment: what was the output you got?

Comment: table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, column_name, ordinal_position. . .

Comment: in the result the `column_name` have the name of the columns in the table..

Comment: are you saying you want the name of all columns in one row?

Comment: Oops. Thanks guys. I already got it.

Comment: please post you answer..

Answer (score 3):

If you want all column names in a single row, you need to aggregate those names:

```
SELECT table_name, string_agg(column_name, ', ' order by ordinal_position) as columns
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'codes'
  AND table_name   = 'watch_list'
GROUP BY table_name;
```

If you remove the condition on the table name, you get this for all tables in that schema.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'
```

Comment: That will display all _tables_ in a schema. The OP wants all _columns_ for one table.

Comment: This will help you: SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name   = 'watch_list'

Comment: Which is essentially the same query as already shown in the question and it will not show the columns in a single row, but will show one row in the result for each column